# Handle duplicates without removing them from database

Tags: mysql, sql

**I would like to know if there's some regular way to handle duplicates in the database without actually removing the duplicated rows. Or a specific name for what I'm trying to achieve, so I can check it out.**

Why would I keep duplicates? Because I have to monitor them. I have to know that they're duplicates and are not e.g. searchable, but at the same time, I have to keep them, because I update the rows from external source and if I'd remove them, they'd go back to the database as soon as I update from external source.

I have two ideas:

1. Have an additional boolean column "searchable", but I feel it's a partial solution, it can turn out to be insufficient in the future
2. Have an additional column "duplicate_of". It would keep id of the column of which the row is duplicate. It would be a foreign key of the same table which is kind of weird., isn't it?

I know it's not a specific programming question, but I think that someone must have handled a similar situation (Facebook - Pages  they keep track of those which are duplicates of others) and it would be great to know a verified solution.

**EDIT**: these are close duplicates, indetified mainly by their location (lat, lng), so DISTINCT is probably not a solution here

Comment: What kind of scale are you dealing with here?

Comment: currently approximately 100k rows, but probably few millions of them. 50-75% are duplicates

Answer (score 2):

I would create a view that has `DISTINCT` values. Having an additional column to be searchable sounds tedious. Your second idea is actually more feasible and there is nothing weird about a self-referencing table.

Comment: A `VIEW` is a great way to hide otherwise obnoxious filtering criteria.

Comment: I updated my question, DISTINCT wouldn't work here, but thanks for mentioning "self_referencing"

Comment: @MichałK Reading your update, can you show further why `DISTINCT` wouldn't work?

Comment: Because lat and lng values should be exactly the same. Given the precision of lat and lng, they're slightly different. But when I think about it, I could run a cron job to search for close duplicates by lat lng and turn them to exact duplicates (change lat and lng to be exactly the same). Adn then use DISTINCT with both columns

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends on several other factors.  In particular, does the database support real deletes and updates (apart from setting the duplication information)?

You have a range of solutions.  One is to place distinct values in a separate table, periodically.  This works well if you have batch inserts, and no updates/deletes.

If you have a database that is being updated, then you might want to maintain a version number on the record.  This lets you track it.  Presumably, if it is a duplicate, there is another duplicate key inside it.

The problem with your second approach is that it can result in a tree-like structure of duplicates.  Where A-->B-->C and D--> so A and D are duplicates, but this is not obvious.  If you always put in the earliest value *and* there are no updates or deletes, then this solution is reasonable.

Comment: I think it would be reasonable, because there's always one "master" row and other are "sub" rows. I have to think about it though, because maybe I'm missing something here. Thanks!